# With exists vs without exists in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How would my output change if I remove exists statement from the following query.

```
UPDATE AR_CRDT C
set (OPERATOR_ID,UPDT_TS) = ( SELECT AD.OPERATOR_ID,sysdate
                FROM
                (
                    Select A.*
                    FROM AR1_CUSTOMER_CREDIT A      
                 )AD 
                 WHERE AD.CREDIT_ID = C.CRDT_ID

                 )
where exists    ( SELECT 1
                FROM
                (
                    Select A.*
                    FROM AR1_CUSTOMER_CREDIT A          
                 )AD 
                  WHERE AD.CREDIT_ID = C.CRDT_ID
                 );
```

Comment: This is analogous to the difference between an inner join and a left outer join. It actually **is** the difference between inner and outer join, if you rewrite your `update` to be an update of a join, as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/8061/update-with-joins#t=201702151427027709587

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `exists`, then `OPERATOR_ID` and `UPDT_TS` would be set to `NULL` for rows where the conditions do not match.

Why would you write this with the extra subqueries?

```
UPDATE AR_CRDT C
    SET (OPERATOR_ID, UPDT_TS) = (SELECT AD.OPERATOR_ID, sysdate
                                  FROM AR1_CUSTOMER_CREDIT A      
                                  WHERE A.CREDIT_ID = C.CRDT_ID
                                 )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM AR1_CUSTOMER_CREDIT A          
                  WHERE A.CREDIT_ID = C.CRDT_ID
                 );
```

Comment: The extra subqueries could be there to make copy-pasting the exact subquery from above easier.

Comment: Thank you gordon. I removed the unwanted subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

The EXISTS currently causes the updates to AR_CRDT to be limited to those records where the AR_CRDT record is associated with an AR1_CUSTOMER_CREDIT record.

Removing that clause will mean that ALL records of AR_CRDT will be updated. Some will have values for the sub-query and some will be NULL where there is no link between AR_CRDT and AR1_CUSTOMER_CREDIT.